# Actual phone layout is not matching eclipse layout

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, screen-resolution

I would appreciate if someone could please help with a layout issue for android using eclipse.
I have a layout defined as "layout-W360dp-H640dp" for an LG-P769 phone that has a 540 x 960 pixel resolution with a size of 4.5". I also defined a layout for the landscape mode "layout-W640dp-H360dp".
The problem is that when I run my app on my phone, the layout is much more compressed and does not match what I see in eclipse.
I use all dp and sp in my design, so I can't figure this problem out.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#FF012209"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp" >

   <GridLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:background="#FF012209"
       android:columnCount="4"
       android:columnOrderPreserved="true"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:paddingLeft="0dp"
       android:rowCount="9"
       android:rowOrderPreserved="true"
       android:useDefaultMargins="true"
       tools:context="com.test_app.MainActivity" >

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/twoButton"
           android:layout_width="70dp"
           android:layout_height="70dp"
           android:layout_column="1"
           android:layout_columnSpan="2"
           android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
           android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
           android:layout_row="0"
           android:background="@drawable/button"
           android:gravity="fill_vertical|center"
           android:textColor="@android:color/white"
           android:textSize="40sp" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/oneButton"
           android:layout_width="70dp"
           android:layout_height="70dp"
           android:layout_column="0"
           android:layout_columnSpan="1"
           android:layout_gravity="top|center"
           android:layout_margin="0dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
           android:layout_row="1"
           android:background="@drawable/button"
           android:textColor="@android:color/white"
           android:textSize="40sp" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/threeButton"
           android:layout_width="70dp"
           android:layout_height="70dp"
           android:layout_column="3"
           android:layout_columnSpan="1"
           android:layout_gravity="top|center"
           android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
           android:layout_row="1"
           android:background="@drawable/button"
           android:textColor="@android:color/white"
           android:textSize="40sp" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/fiveButton"
           android:layout_width="70dp"
           android:layout_height="70dp"
           android:layout_column="0"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
           android:layout_row="5"
           android:background="@drawable/button"
           android:textColor="@android:color/white"
           android:textSize="40sp" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/sixButton"
           android:layout_width="70dp"
           android:layout_height="70dp"
           android:layout_column="1"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
           android:layout_row="5"
           android:background="@drawable/button"
           android:textColor="@android:color/white"
           android:textSize="40sp" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/sevenButton"
           android:layout_width="70dp"
           android:layout_height="70dp"
           android:layout_column="2"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
           android:layout_row="5"
           android:background="@drawable/button"
           android:textColor="@android:color/white"
           android:textSize="40sp" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/nineButton"
           android:layout_width="80dp"
           android:layout_height="80dp"
           android:layout_column="0"
           android:layout_columnSpan="2"
           android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
           android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
           android:layout_row="6"
           android:background="@drawable/button"
           android:textColor="@android:color/white"
           android:textSize="20sp" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/tenButton"
           android:layout_width="80dp"
           android:layout_height="80dp"
           android:layout_column="2"
           android:layout_columnSpan="2"
           android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
           android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
           android:layout_row="6"
           android:background="@drawable/button"
           android:textColor="@android:color/white"
           android:textSize="20sp" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/fourButton"
           android:layout_width="70dp"
           android:layout_height="70dp"
           android:layout_column="1"
           android:layout_columnSpan="2"
           android:layout_gravity="top|center"
           android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
           android:layout_row="3"
           android:background="@drawable/button"
           android:textColor="@android:color/white"
           android:textSize="40sp" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/twelveButton"
           android:layout_width="70dp"
           android:layout_height="70dp"
           android:layout_column="2"
           android:layout_columnSpan="2"
           android:layout_gravity="top|center"
           android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
           android:layout_row="7"
           android:background="@drawable/button"
           android:textColor="@android:color/white"
           android:textSize="40sp" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/elevenButton"
           android:layout_width="70dp"
           android:layout_height="70dp"
           android:layout_column="0"
           android:layout_columnSpan="2"
           android:layout_gravity="top|center"
           android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
           android:layout_row="7"
           android:background="@drawable/button"
           android:textColor="@android:color/white"
           android:textSize="40sp" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/thirteenButton"
           android:layout_width="70dp"
           android:layout_height="70dp"
           android:layout_column="1"
           android:layout_columnSpan="2"
           android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
           android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
           android:layout_row="8"
           android:background="@drawable/button"
           android:textColor="@android:color/white"
           android:textSize="20sp" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/eightButton"
           android:layout_width="70dp"
           android:layout_height="70dp"
           android:layout_column="3"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
           android:layout_row="5"
           android:background="@drawable/button"
           android:textColor="@android:color/white"
           android:textSize="40sp" />

   </GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should use standard dpi resolution layouts instead of specifically sized ones (eg xhdpi).

Comment: I added "layout-hdpi" and my xml file looks good in eclipse, but still shows incorrectly on my actual phone. Using the debugger and the getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(dm), I verified the pixel resolution to be 540 x 960.

Comment: My app is targeted for Android 3.2 and above. I read many recommendations for setting up layouts and have spent weeks trying to get them all to look good but have not had success. For now, I would like to at least figure out how to get eclipse to match what is on the actual phone. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Post your layout I guess?

Comment: OK, I deleted all my other definitions and only have ldpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi. The LGP769 and Nexus S both use the hdpi layout, but the Nexus S is expanded beyond the screen. I tried to post the xml layout here, but it's too long to fit.

Comment: Sorry any way to post my layout? I tried a very truncated version and it also was too long to post. It's basically buttons on a grid layout, in a linear layout.

Comment: Edit your question and include it, look at how to format code into your question (basically adding 4 spaces starts a code block).

Comment: Thanks for the instructions! code is posted.

Comment: I'm beginning to suspect that maybe I'm expecting too much from this layout method. Let me ask this question - Are many of the professional apps dynamically set? Meaning, is the resolution & density of the device read and then buttons and margins etc. sized accordingly? Is this a reasonable method? Please advise on this. Thanks!